# Altering model's columns if another model's column has a certain value

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

So, I have the following code:

```
$query = Good::query();    
$query->with('availabilities_good.availability.truck');
$rows = $query->get();
```

I grab the `goods` from the database along with the `availabilities` asociated with them through the `availabilities_good` pivot table.
Now, `availability` model has a `truck` relationship.
Truck model has the following columns: `id`, `car_plate` and `vin`.
Is there a way that I can alter the `car_plate` value on the fly(while eager loading) based on a `good`'s column value?

Eg.: if the `good`'s `status` column has the value `active` then I want to replace `car_plate`'s characters with `******` as in hiding it, otherwise, leave it untouched.

I know I can do this with a `foreach` loop on the `$rows` array but I'm asking if there's a way to do this while eager loading.

Thank you.

Comment: you can use Raw DB query, mysql IF() :
SELECT IF(good.status = 1,"*****", truck.car_plate) as car_plate

Answer (score -1):

one option is to use Raw DB Query as follows :

```php
Good::select(DB::raw('IF(good.status = 1,"*****", truck.car_plate) as car_plate'))->get();
```

Comment: I see, but would it be possible to use Raw DB query while still not letting go of eloquent? adding the Raw DB to a closure only on `truck` model inside `with`?